# Why is the authorization context with multiple PSGI applications in Catalyst not working?

Tags: perl, perl-module, catalyst

I have tow cascading Plack middleware applications(`app1`, `app2`), `app1` is the front application. I followed these tutorials:

- http://advent.plackperl.org/2009/12/day-10-using-plack-middleware.html
- http://advent.plackperl.org/2009/12/day-19-cascade-multiple-applications.html

This is my code:

```
use Plack::App::Cascade;
use Plack::App::URLMap;
use lib "/var/www/app1/lib",
    "/var/www/app2/lib";
use app1;
use app2;

my $app1 = app1->psgi_app(@_);
my $app2 = app2->psgi_app(@_);

my $app_map1 = Plack::App::URLMap->new;
$app_map2->mount( '/' => $app1 );

my $app2 = Plack::App::URLMap->new;
$app2->mount( '/app2' => $app2 );

Plack::App::Cascade->new(apps => [ $app_map1, $app_map2 ])->to_app;
```

Until now everything is ok, I added also the authentication functionality, and for that i used these two catalyst modules:  [Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Catalyst-Plugin-Authentication-0.10023/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/Authentication.pm) and [Catalyst::Plugin::Authorization::Abilities](http://search.cpan.org/~idoperel/Catalyst-Plugin-Authorization-Abilities-v0.31.0/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/Authorization/Abilities.pm).

The authentication part is working fine for the two applications (user logged from `app1`), but I got a problem for the authorization part just for `app2`. When I try to figure out, it was the context variable `$c`. The `app1` `$c` variable was not the same as `app2`. After authentication (from `app1`) I got a user object `$c->user`, but for the second application I had a new `$c` created and the `$c->user` is not found.

**So how can these two applications get the same context `$c`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution but before that let me explain the situation:

PSGI with muti middelware applications have same limitation. Each middleware behaves as a separate application and each one create its own session. In case, we have the authentication feature(applied for all middelware) we got a prob here. like the example above, the `app1` had the session of the authenticated user but `app2` had just an anonymous session.

So to fixe it. I create a shared memory to store sessions. For that, me must change  [Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Store::File](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/Catalyst-Plugin-Session-Store-File-0.18/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/Session/Store/File.pm) with [Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Store::FastMmap](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Catalyst-Plugin-Session-Store-FastMmap-0.16/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/Session/Store/FastMmap.pm) for `app1` and `app2`.

Then add this config in `app2.pm`:

```
 'Plugin::Session' => {
        cookie_name => 'app1_session',
        storage => '/tmp/app1/session_data',
    }
```